# Jquery setting checkbox to disabled also sets checked to false

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following line of code

```
$("#mytable td :checkbox").prop("disabled", true);
```

When the page is posted and returns to itself (ie due to a validation issue etc) this line causes the checkboxes to be set to disabled (as wanted) but also sets the checked status to false of all checkboxes already set to checked. If I take this line out then obviously the checkboxes do not get disabled but they keep their checked statuses.

However if the page is navigated to via another page then this line works fine and sets the checkbox to disabled and keeps its checked status.

What on earth could be going on?

Comment: Hmm.. What browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because disabled inputs (including checkboxes) are not submitted. So if checkbox changed its state, the new value will not be submitted.

Comment: The issue is on the get not the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .attr property instead of .prop

```
$("#mytable td :checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
```

.attr initial state of checkbox does not chang
.prop changes the state according to change in properties

check the documentation for reference

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#mytable td :checkbox").attr('onclick','return false');
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Jquery line was a red herring. The actual issue was with Asp.Net MVC the modelstate was overriding the models values due to it posting back to itself. Calling modelstate.clear() fixed the issue.